# How can I sort a file with a lot of variables as to 1

Tags: r, file, sorting

If I have a file like the one in the picture and I want to sort it based on a variable out of the 15 I have in total, how can I sort all the columns without spoiling the proper match?

[image]

```
> dput(head(data1))
structure(list(PRICE = c(47, 113, 165, 104.3, 62.5, 70), NROOM = c(4L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L), NBATH = c(1, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5), PATIO = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), FIREPL = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AC = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), BMENT = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), NSTOR = c(3, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3), GAR = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L), AGE = c(148L, 
9L, 23L, 5L, 19L, 20L), SQFT = c(11.25, 28.92, 30.62, 26.12, 
22.04, 39.42), SQMT = c(104.51592, 268.67559168, 284.46910848, 
242.66274048, 204.75830016, 366.22378368), SIZE = c("Medium", 
"Large", "Large", "Large", "Large", "Large"), HC = structure(c(5L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("New", "Neither New nor Old", 
"Relatively Old", "Old", "Very Old-Antique"), class = "factor"), 
    PRSQMT = c(0.449692257409206, 0.42058156192538, 0.580027831076781, 
    0.429814646425277, 0.305237931508329, 0.191139961737616)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894246/how-to-sort-a-data-frame-in-r

Comment: Jon in this example you sent , we are having 1 only column instead of 15 i have

Comment: Quinten i pressed "dput(data1)" and one column mixed with the other. Should i do something else instead of that ?

Comment: Hi @ThodorisSagias, That is right just do `dput(data1)` in your console and copy-paste the output in your question above.

Comment: I am having 202 rows in total so i dont think that will help you but i will do it anyway. Just give me a minute.

Comment: @ThodorisSagias, `dput(head(data1))` is also fine.

Comment: Yeah much better.

Comment: @ThodorisSagias, Please do not post it as an image. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `data1[order(data1$Your_column), ]`. This is what @JonSpring's link does and it should work in your case.

Comment: You are right. My bad. Sorry @JonSpring and thank you all for your time guys <3